# HTML DOM childNodes

Tags: html, dom

I was playing around with HTML DOM, and I noticed that two properties don't agree with each other with no apparent reason. Consider this simple HTML file:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
<p>Isn't this exciting?</p>
<p>You're learning to use the DOM!</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

I expected `body` and `alt_body` to be identical, but .childNodes insists giving me a text node. (Below is the content of script.js)

```
body = document.documentElement.childNodes[1]
alt_body = document.documentElement.lastChild;  
console.log(body.nodeType) //prints 3 (Node.TEXT_NODE)
console.log(alt_body.nodeType) //prints 1 (Node.ELEMENT_NODE)
console.log(body.childNodes.length) //prints 0
console.log(alt_body.childNodes.length) //prints 8
```

Does anyone know why it's acting that way?

Comment: Why should the second child node be the same as the last one?

Answer (score 1):

**It's because `childNodes` returns a text line node as well**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>DOM Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello World!</p>
        <p>Isn't this exciting?</p>
        <p>You're learning to use the DOM!</p>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

1. 0 : will be `<head>` node
2. 1 : will be `empty text` ( considered as a node )
3. 2 : will be `<body>` node ( `lastChild` in this HTML )

---

Try after getting rid of all the linefeeds and spaces like this below.

```
<html><head><title>DOM Example</title></head><body><p>Hello World!</p><p>Isn't this exciting?</p><p>You're learning to use the DOM!</p></body><script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script></html>
```

Then the result will be what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

`childNodes[1]` isn't the last child, because there are three children:

- [0] The Head Element
- [1] The Text Node containing the newline character between your `</head>` and `<body>`.
- [2] The body element

If you were to remove the newline and all spaces between `</head>` and `<body>` you would find that `childNodes[1] === lastChild`:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>DOM Example</title>
</head><body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
<p>Isn't this exciting?</p>
<p>You're learning to use the DOM!</p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```